# Path Connections in Coarse Finite Topologies

Tags: general-topology

I just had the following question on an exam:

> Is the topology given by the subbase $\{a,c,d\}, \{a,c,b\}$ path connected?

I wasn't sure about this, my guess is that its not. I sketched the following:

The topology is $\big\{\{a,c,d\}, \{a,c,b\},\{a,c\}, \{a,c,b,d\}\big\}$. Then noted the limit of a constant sequence $(c)$ can have two limits - $a$ or $c$. (Indeed check every open set containing $a$ and see that it also contains $c$). I think this will force a path to be not uniquely defined. I'm not sure though. Thoughts?

Comment: Every connected finite space is path-connected. Paths need only exist, they don’t need to be unique.

Comment: The constantly $c$ sequence also has limits $b$ and $d$. Not that it matters much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finite spaces are pretty weird in some ways. In this [introductory paper](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/MISC/FiniteSpaces.pdf) by May it is shown (proposition 4.8) that a connected finite space is in fact path-connected and your space is certainly connected as all non-empty open sets intersects (in $a$ and $c$). The latter also implies that the constant $c$ (or $a$ or alternating if you like) sequence actually  converges to all $4$ points $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: ya, I saw it was connected. so my other thought was to check local path connectedness but I was having trouble breaking down the definition quickly for the reason I mentioned above